# How to use a recursive array

Tags: ruby

I have array, named `a` and define  it with `[1, 2, 3]`.

Next, I pushed it to itself:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a << a
```

and the result I get is:

```
#=> [1, 2, 3, [...]]
```

When I want to get the last element of `array` using `a.last` I get:

```
a.last
#=> [1, 2, 3, [...]]
#even 
a.last.last.last
#=> [1, 2, 3, [...]]
```

What is going on, when we would push array to itself?

Yes, I understand that this should create a recursive array, but what can we do with it?

Comment: *"what we can do with it"* – make coffee if you type enough `.last` and make the CPU produce enough heat…? I'm not sure what kind of answer you're expecting here…

Comment: I didn't know ruby handles it this well :)

Comment: @deceze I mean, maybe someone know how to use `recursive array` in real work examples

Comment: I'm sure there *are* real world use cases for this, and you will know them when you encounter them. Coming up with random examples is not really a productive question for SO.

Comment: They're pretty useful in Mathematics, as couter-examples. Your recursive array is basicaly infinitely long. If you make one step towards infinity, you basically didn't move at all ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby variables, array elements etc. are object references. So when you do `a = [1, 2, 3]`, there will be an array somewhere in memory and the `a` variable is a reference to that memory. Now when you do `a << a`, `a[4]` will also be a reference to that object. So in effect `a` now contains a reference to itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a << a.dup
a.last
=> [1, 2, 3]  
a.last.last
=> 3
```

Maybe this is what you wanted. This just insert an array `[1, 2, 3]` as the last item of the a array. In the way you did you put a reference at the end of the a array and this becomes recursive.